# Find zero and one element for given ring

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ring-theory

Given $ M$ and the powerset $\mathcal{P}(M) $, 
let $A,B \subseteq M$ and define:
$A \bigoplus B := A \backslash B \cup B \backslash A$
$A * B := A \cap B$
Then is $R_M = \langle \mathcal{P}(M); \bigoplus, *\rangle$ a commutative ring.

What is the zero element and whats the one element of $R_M$?
And what is $R^\times_M$?

I Know that for the one element (e.g. 1 being the element): $1*A = A*1 = A$
And for the zero element (e.g. 0 being the element): $0*A=0$

But how do I transfer this to my sets?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The zero element is the empty set, the one element is the whole set. The latter is the only unit.

Comment: Can you provide something for me to understand how you came to this conclusion?

Comment: Also, $R^\times _M=\left\{M\right\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the identity of the $\ast$ operation, think about what you're doing. You need to find a set such that when you intersect it with any other subset of $X$ of $M$, you still get $X$ back. That means that your candidate must be a superset of all subsets of $M$...

For the identity of the $\oplus$ operation, think along similar lines. You need a set such that for any subset $X$ of $M$, the symmetric difference of $X$ and the set is just $X$. In particular your candidate must be contained in the complement of $X$ for every subset $X$ of $M$...

These lines of thought lead to the answers. But seriously, the answers are the likely suspects. You really should have checked them first!

Let $1$ be the $\ast $ identity, and let's think about all the units of this ring. It turns out that that units are as sparse as they get in this ring. Verify that $A\ast A=A$ for every $A$ in the ring. Suppose $A\ast B=1$ (i.e. that $A$ is a unit!) and then combine that with the information about $A\ast A=A$ to draw a conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This topic is completely new for me, so forgive my lack of knowledge :)

Comment: Is my zero/one element supposed to be used for both $*$ and $\bigoplus$?

Comment: @Peter I think you were thinking of the wrong definition of "zero element". The zero element is the identity for $\oplus$: $A\oplus 0=A$ for all $A\in R$. You can deduce that $A\ast 0=0$ for all $A$ after you have your candidate for $0$, which I believe you already have :)

Comment: Is there a formal way to write this reasoning with mathematical symbols? Like: $A \cap \{\} = \{\}$, but for the one element?

Comment: @Peter Sure: $A\ast 0:=A\cap\emptyset=\emptyset:=0$. I'm using the $:=$ to say "this equality is given by definition."

Comment: That I did already understand, but how comes M is the one elment? I feel so stupid :(

Comment: @Peter Let's try it out: $A\ast 1:=A\cap M=$? What's the result? $A$ right? Because $A\subseteq M$! This shows $M$ acts like the identity element of $\ast$, and as [Connor Macleod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highlander_(franchise)) says, *there can only be one* .

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\notag \\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \notag \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\notag \end{align}}
$To me, it seems the simplest approach is to *calculate* $\;0\;$ and $\;1\;$.

For $\;0\;$, we know that $\;0 \oplus A = A\;$ for all $\;A\;$.  And it helps to know that a simpler definition of $\;\oplus\;$ is
$$
\tag{0} x \in A \oplus B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$
Using this, and letting $\;x\;$ implicitly range over $\;M\;$, we calculate

$$\calc
\langle \forall A :: 0 \oplus A = A \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{set extensionality; definition (0) for $\;\oplus\;$}
\langle \forall A :: \langle \forall x :: x \in 0 \not\equiv x \in A \equiv x \in A \rangle \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify}
\langle \forall A :: \langle \forall x :: x \not\in 0 \rangle \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\emptyset\;$; logic: remove unused $\;\forall A\;$}
0 = \emptyset
\endcalc$$

For $\;1\;$ we know that $\;1 * A = A\;$ for all $\;A\;$, so we calculate

$$\calc
\langle \forall A :: 1 * A = A \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;*\;$}
\langle \forall A :: 1 \cap A = A \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{set extentionality; definition of $\;\cap\;$}
\langle \forall A :: \langle \forall x :: x \in 1 \land x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in A \rangle \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify $\;P \equiv P \land Q\;$ to $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$; merge $\;\forall\;$ quantifications}
\langle \forall A,x :: x \not\in A \;\lor\; x \in 1 \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify by moving parts not using $\;A\;$ out of $\;\forall A\;$}
\langle \forall x :: \langle \forall A :: x \not\in A \rangle \;\lor\; x \in 1 \rangle\calcop{\equiv}{$\;\langle \forall A :: x \not\in A \rangle\;$ is false, witness $\;A := \{x\}\;$; simplify}
\langle \forall x :: x \in 1 \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{$\;x\;$ ranges over $\;M\;$; definition of $\;\subseteq\;$; $\;1 \subseteq M\;$}
1 = M
\endcalc$$

This completes the calculation of both identities.